# Android LiveData Observer Not Triggered

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am trying to add an observer in my activity but it never seems to get triggered.

I have a button on my app which makes a sensor connected to my phone start measuring data when the sensors are measuring it hits a callback in my `XsDevice()` class.

Here is the code in my `XsDevice()` class

```
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Float>> accelerationData = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<ArrayList<Float>> freeAccDataLiveData = accelerationData;


@Override
public void onXsensDotDataChanged(String s, XsensDotData xsensDotData) {
    ArrayList<Float> result = new ArrayList();

    for (Float freeAcc: xsensDotData.getFreeAcc()) {
        result.add(freeAcc);
    }
    accelerationData.postValue(result);
}
```

When the callback function is hit I am using `postValue(result)` to update the `accelerationData` variable, this is where me being a new to android development comes in.

I am presuming after I post the value the `freeAccDataLiveData` variable is updated and this is what I am observing.

Here is my observer code in my activity

```
private XsDevice xsDeviceClass = new XsDevice();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    xsDeviceClass.freeAccDataLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Float>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<Float> freeAccData) {
            for(int i = 0; i < freeAccData.size(); i++){
                Log.d("Free Acceleration Data", String.valueOf(freeAccData.get(i)));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The `...` is just a placeholder for the standard `onCreate` code I haven't included.

The issue I am having is `Log.d("Free Acceleration Data", String.valueOf(freeAccData.get(i)));` is never logged which must mean the observer isn't working. If I added this log directly to the callback function it works fine but I need to get the data in my `MainActivity`

Is there something simple I might have missed?

Comment: Are you sure `xsensDotData.getFreeAcc()` returns non empty list/array? Try adding logs near `result.add(freeAcc);`.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I just double check by adding the exact same Log line to the callback function and replaced `freeAccData` with `result` and the logs were being displayed

Comment: I tested exactly the same code as you posted. If onXsensDotDataChanged is called and set non-empty list, the observer will receive it without any changes. Please add more log to make sure.

Comment: Does your activity always stay open? Maybe it is finished and when created again you expect to see some results. Are you sure this is the same `XsDevice` instance that posts an update?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu @Brian I just realised that it is a different instance of `XsDevice` because I am running `startMeasuring()` from a different activity, When I run `startMeasuring()` in the same activity it works. How can I observe from a different activity? Sorry for my mistake!

Comment: "How can I observe from a different activity?" - you can make `XsDevice` class a [singleton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm). I was going to suggest re-implementing it as a [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) but it will require a little bit of excessive trickery to make it work *for two activities*. Consider making it a singleton. That will solve the issue 100% but make create other issues - depends on your application and how `XsDevice` is used.

Answer (score 0):

The observer of livedata will be called only when data is changed by set or post. Thus, if you did not initialize the value in the XsDevice class, it won't be called until data is assigned.

If you want to get callback in OnCreate method by default, need to set the default value of accelerationData like this. Then, you can get callback right after you register an observer.

```
class XsDevice {
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Float>> accelerationData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public LiveData<ArrayList<Float>> freeAccDataLiveData = accelerationData;

    public XsDevice() {
        accelerationData.postValue(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, please make sure onXsensDotDataChanged is called as you expected and freeAccData is not empty. Otherwise, you cannot see the log even though it is called.

Comment: Hi I added the log to the `onXsensDotDataChanged` function to double check it was being called and it was, I'm not sure why the observer isnt being triggered